# How to change JWT payload?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, jwt, penetration-testing

I am doing penetration tests and I have this JWT. 
[JWT here](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJhcnRoeW9AcG9zdC5jeiIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiI4NGUzN2VmYi01MWFmLTRlMDAtOWM4MC1jNjg3NDU1NjljYzUiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJteS1jbGllbnQiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiLCJ0cnVzdCJdfQ.QabnOXcPw_fqyk-vrgixfJG2Rxb4k7AE-PnpFLaqXvpwcsQXJxJh0Xd0oCFbgA6V1EbLlj1riaFwGLUusGlw60zYbXGSWTewP0H2jEe0JrMgPeH6vgxoRnoPT0PE2ti_mYqSj0m-SMxwTvH_zi7a1B8kqb-z2zPaShzIdNu2Vey6Y8kOa2p5A5nWmcUe9Cj8_58y2pIVjYhv0hmC4XCHRrVgsTno-Ydvigpzcq3n2Y4_HgKek_ggyzg-xQDdrAiSbOzDFRUy1ZDIbvO6o6nMmOTyTu8dJA_EaSo29q5dr3XNmVq0dT2X03YdZfZKCK7bIaGXGxOmpfLHhVdSp56zIQ)
It is signed by private key on the server side. I need to change the payload in order to do some penetration test. So I would change payload... for example: ROLES: [ROLE_ADMIN] instead of current content. How can I do that?

Comment: it has to be re-signed IMO

Comment: And how to do that as far as the penetration tests are concerned? How should I re-sign it? With the same key as the server?

Comment: Yes it would need the same key. Of course there is a possibility of hash collision meaning two different payloads hash to the same value so that can be exploited as well, but that payload might not be what you want

Comment: thanks. So the test should be like: Decode JWT, change payload, encode JWT with the server key and send back to the server? Is it correct? Is there any more tests that could be done which are related with JWT?

Comment: yes that sequence would certainly change the payload correctly (as if server had done it itself).